# Firebase Crash log not reporting for IOS React Native app

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I have implemented all the steps depicted in firebase official document for Firebase Crashlytics. I have cross-checked few times to make sure I don't miss any step.I referred this doc for implementation [;l[steps for implementation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios) Also I uploaded DSYM files in firebase console assuming if dSYM files are not generating automatically. Still no crash is appearing in firebase console. I forced a crash for testing as mentioned in this doc[enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash?authuser=0&platform=ios)but no luck. Can someone please help me get crash logs in my firebase console?

Note: It is working perfectly in Android and logging crashes in console for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS Crashalytics started working once I unlinked it from fabric.